# How to install Fly CLI to mac

Tags: continuous-integration, concourse

I download the latest version of the Fly cli

https://concourse-ci.org/download.html

to `~/Downloads` then `cd` to `~/Downloads`

```
cd ~/Downloads
mv fly_darwin_amd64 fly
install fly
```

then I do

```
fly
```

and i get

> -bash: fly: command not found

Is one of my steps wrong?

Answer (score 29):

Try

`cd ~/Downloads
mv fly_darwin_amd64 /usr/local/bin/fly
chmod 0700 /usr/local/bin/fly (Thanks to @Andrew Ramnikov)
For the newest mac os version, you need to allow the App to run from System Settings->Security and Privacy->General-> Allow app
fly -version`

Comment: If u get an error: "zsh: permission denied: fly" than u need to run the following command: chmod 0700 /usr/local/bin/fly

Answer (score 15):

On MacOS, you can install with brew like, `brew install --cask fly`.

You might also want to install CredHub to manage credentials, `brew install cloudfoundry/tap/credhub-cli`.

Comment: brew install --cask fly

Comment: after downloading, It shows - “fly” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

Comment: In terminal, type `where fly` - it'll probably be something like `/opt/homebrew/bin/fly` - cd into `/opt/homebrew/bin` and type `open .` - double click the fly file and accept. You should be able to use fly cli now.

Answer (score 6):

On Apple Silicon (Mac Studio M1 Max) this worked for me.

**1. Install with Homebrew**

This will install it as cask, even though it should not be; you can see it under fly -> /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/fly/7.9.1/fly

```
brew install fly
```

**2. Navigate to symlink in Finder**
In my case I ran:

```
cd /opt/homebrew/bin
open .
```

**3. Find fly link**
Then **Right-click** and hit Open in the warning dialog. Terminal will briefly flash. You should see the synopsis for running fly and "Exited" at the end. Close that terminal window.

**4. Verify**

Just run:

```
fly -version
```

In my case the output was 7.9.1

Answer (score 4):

Note that in the accepted answer, in Catalina and Newer the equivalent to the last step to allow the app in privacy settings is: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/fly`
And this does not require admin rights, but doing it via the GUI does.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System Preferences` -> `Security & Privacy` -> `General` and click `allow anyway` next the the `fly` app.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the fly binary to a folder in my home directory, and just added it to my path variable in `~/.bash_profile` so I guess it works now.

**edit**

However, when I do

```
fly -t main login
```

I get

> error: unknown target: main

Comment: When you login, you need to provide concourse url as well. So the command should be fly -t main login --concourse-url your_concourse_url

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to run first command `curl 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cli?arch=amd64&platform=darwin' -o fly \ && chmod +x ./fly` which will create a `fly` binary and for the second part of command just do it manually `&& mv ./fly /usr/local/bin/` meaning you need to copy fly binary into /usr/local/bin